# Why does my SQL join query return null results, can it be optimized?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

The problem I have is that when I run the following query

```sql
SELECT Series.*
FROM School, Series AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SeriesSchool on SeriesSchool.SeriesID = s.SeriesID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Series on SeriesSchool.SchoolID = s.SeriesID
WHERE SeriesSchool.SchoolID = 1
```

## I get some results but the values are all `NULL`

[image]

---

### Database Schema

[image: Database Schema]

### Database Content

[image: Database content]

> Frontend devs don't eat together because they don't know how to **JOIN TABLES**

Comment: Do you want get Image from Gallery and Camera through Dialog that show you option to pic image from gallery and capture from camera  ?

Comment: for Cropping Image crate an class and define your Crop method Then Call that method creating object of Crop class in any activity you Want.

Comment: Sorry, I had to completely change this old post because I wasn't permitted to ask more questions.

Comment: _Sorry, I had to completely change this old post because I wasn't permitted to ask more questions_ That is too confusing. The comments by Saurabh Bh. are entirely irrelevant because of your edit. This cannot be the best way!

Comment: What else could I do? I wasn't permitted to ask any more questions. I really need the answer